# Change part of edittext text color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

Is there a way to change the color of part of an edittext text?
In my application user can tag his friends in a post using their usernames, now I want to change the username color to blue while the user is still typing so he know that he successfully tagged his friend (exactly like tagging friends in Facebook)
I still don't have any code because I didn't know how to start! any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need color treatment to the usernames in an `EditText`, you can use `Spannable`s. In this case `ForegroundColorSpan` would be a good start.

A simplified solution looks something like:

```
String usernameToLookFor = "michael";
String myString = "Welcome world to michael !!";

//Create spannable string
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(myString);

//Determine the start and end of the span i.e. which section you want colored
//Note: loop it if username appears multiple times in main string
int usernameStart = myString.indexOf(usernameToLookFor);
int usernameEnd = usernameStart + usernameToLookFor.length;

//Apply color spannable to SpannableString
spannableString.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.highlighted_color)),usernameStart, usernameEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

//Set spannable to edit text
myEditText.setText(spannableString);
```

Very rough answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert an html in your code into the textView, then you can define a color in a especific part of the text:

```
myTextView
.setText(
  Html.fromHtml(
   "Your text<span color='<your color>'>colored part</span> rest of your text"
));
```

Comment: does this work the same for an EditText? because the user will be typing inside an EditText